# Multi-line email body in JSX

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, jsx

I am trying to create an email with a multi line body using:

```
<a href={"mailto:" + this.state.emailsToNotify + 
         "?subject=" + this.state.mname 
         + "&body=Please, review: " + "\n" + this.state.mname + "\n" + "at " + emailBody 

        }>
    <button style={button4TableStyleObject('#007a86', '#ebf5ff', '#ff3900 #ff3900')} >{'Notify Selected'} </button>
</a>
```

However Outlook opens this email using a single line. Is there a way to make it multi-line? I used `"\n"` with double quotes but no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to encode the parameters you pass in a `mailto:` url. For a line break, you can use `%0A`:

```html
<a href="mailto:foo@example.com?body=First%20line%0Asecond%20line%0A%0ANew%20paragraph">your message here</a>
```

In order to not have to do this manually, you can use `encodeURIComponent()`:

```js
console.log(encodeURIComponent(`first line
second line

paragraph`));
```

Comment: Now that you mention it, I believe exist: encodeURIComponent
I'll try both! thx

Comment: While you posted your comment, I just updated my answer including `encodeURIComponent()`:)

Comment: I think `encodeURIComponent()` is the right way to go, because on Windows a line break would be `%0D%0A`.

Comment: Most clients should handle a regular `\n` line-break well, independent of the OS, and as you don't know the target OS of the mail recipient, you'd have to use `\r\n` in any case if you wanted to be sure.